# Use IF and IF AND in the same formula

Tags: excel-formula

I believe my sytanx is right but I cannot use IF and AND IF statements in the same formula. Do you know what the issue might be?

=IF(K47>170,"BAD",IF(K47<100,"GOOD"),IF(AND(J47=0,I47>160,"BAD")

Comment: If none worked then please show by example data what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

In excel If is (boolean statement, true result, false result)
And just returns true or false. You can't have a string value. 
so And should be throwing an error because "BAD" can't be evaluated as true or false
and the last if should throw an error because there are enough arguments (it needs three). 
In addition, you don't have enough to bound the formula.

So you should have something like

=if(K47>170, "Bad", if(k47< 100, "Good", if(AND(J47=0,I47>160), "BAD", "SOMETHING")))

Answer (score 0):

Break it down into smaller blocks to isolate the problem. Not tested because I don't have excel but writing the formula as follows

```
  =IF(
    K47>170,
    "BAD",
    IF(
        K47<100,
        "GOOD")
```

^^ looks like you're missing something here because the else part of the innermost if here isn't specified and the statement should be closed with a ) here, meaning excel can't figure out what to do with the rest (below).

```
,IF(AND(J47=0,I47>160,"BAD")
```

This part also has a pretty strange condition. It seems like you want to say " if j47 equals 0 and I47 is greater than 160 ".

In pseudo code, if you want

```
if k47 > 170
    bad
else
    if k47 < 100
        good
    else
        if j47 = 0 and I47 > 160
            bad
        else
            good
    end
end
```

Then you can write it with excel with something like

```
=IF(
    K47 > 170,
    "BAD",
    IF(
        K47 < 100,
        "GOOD",
        IF(
            AND(
                J47 = 0,
                I47 > 160
            ),
           "BAD",
           "GOOD"
        )
    )
)
```

Give it a try and look at the excel formula guide as you go, solving one piece at a time.